# Индексируется только часть файлов

Tags: база-данных, elasticsearch, big-data

Необходимо проиндексировать большое количество (около 100к) файлов формата json разного размера (на 100к файлов приходится в общем 1,2ГГб текстовой информации).

Пишу на python, соответственно использую стандартный модуль для работы с Elasticsearch. Из состава использую функцию helpers.bulk таким образом:

```
es = Elasticsearch(ES_CLUSTER)

json_docs = []
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename) as open_file:
            json_docs.append(json.load(open_file))

helpers.bulk(ES_INDEX, ES_TYPE, json_docs)
```

В результате работы индексируется только 570 файлов. Причем заметил, что размер индекса после каждого нового прогона программы сильно колеблется от 2-4мб до 15мб, хотя количество проиндексированных файлов остается неизменным.

Размер индекса узнаю запросом:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

Очищаю так:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/_all/'
```

Видимо использую не оптимальный способ индексирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очередь на индексацию в Elasticsearch по умолчанию ограничена.Вы пытаетесь скормить ему слишком много записей за раз. Это хоть и Bulk API, но работает он немного по другому:

Необходимо отправлять порции в несколько сотен записей (подбирается экспериментально)

```
es = Elasticsearch(ES_CLUSTER)
json_docs = []
i=0
bulkSize=500
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    i++
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename) as open_file:
            json_docs.append(json.load(open_file))
    if len(json_docs) >= bulkSize:
        print(i, "current file:", datetime.now(), filename)
        try:
            helpers.bulk(ES_INDEX, ES_TYPE, json_docs)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
        del json_docs
        json_docs = []
//do not forget to put rest
helpers.bulk(ES_INDEX, ES_TYPE, json_docs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Мы в своем проекте (не python) тоже индексируем большое кол-во информации. Основные моменты:

1. Мы не индексируем через API - curl из bash
2. Наш скрипт преобразует данные в формат bulk и кусками по 1000 документов складывает в обычный текстовый файл.
3. После обработки всех данных запускаем консольный скрипт:

```bash
files=(${1}*.txt)
total=${#files[@]};
count=0
pstr="[=======================================================================]"

echo "Start export to ElasticSearch ${total} files with data"

for i in ${1}*.txt; do
    curl -XPOST http://elastic.domain.conm/_bulk --data-binary @${i} &>/dev/null
    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
    pd=$(( $count * 73 / $total ))
    printf "\r%3d.%1d%% %.${pd}s" $(( $count * 100 / $total )) $(( ($count * 1000 / $total) % 10 )) $pstr
done

printf "\n"
```